# Getting service error when came back from Facebook handover in node js bot V4

Tags: node.js, json, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot, azure-bot-service

I have written below code to handover the control to page inbox.

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: process.env.FBgraphPassThreadURL,
    qs: { access_token: process.env.FBTOKEN_V4_NAMES },
    headers:
    {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body:
    {
        recipient: { id: stepContext.context._activity.from.id },

        "target_app_id": process.env.HandoverTargetAppId,
        "metadata": "String to pass to secondary receiver app"
    },
    json: true
};

var response;
await rp(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        console.log('--- status---', parsedBody);
        response = parsedBody;

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // POST failed...
        console.log('----from catch ---', err);
        console.log('----from catch ---', err);
    });

console.log('callcenterhandover response-->', response);
return stepContext.endDialog();
```

Now customer successfully handover to page inbox-main folder. when I mark the customer as done then customer come back to bot and bot executing onConversationUpdate event and onMembersAdded event. Hence I consider onConversationUpdate event and written below logic.

```
this.onConversationUpdate(async (context, next) => {
    this.dialog.initialDialogId =** 'handOverWelcomeDialog' **;
    await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);
    await next();
});
```

Now  handOverWelcomeDialog will run and display some welcome message to user and ends the dialog.

Not sure where am doing the mistake and why am getting below error after 1 minute from Bot.

```
[onTurnError]: Error: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError"
  }
}
```

[image: image contain error while reproducing through ngrok]

How can I fix this service error?

Any suggestions please ASAP. Much appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read this? https://blog.botframework.com/2019/06/03/using-the-facebook-messenger-handover-protocol-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Thanks Kyle. That blog referring code in c# but I am working on JavaScript SDK. Please let me know how can I implement in JavaScript SDK. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using that throws this error, and specify which line is throwing the error

Comment: @KyleDelaney, as suggested, I have provided the code in my question. I dont know the the line number which generating  this error. Please suggest where am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Now you're saying the error comes after 1 minute. Are you saying the error comes at a specific time rather than a specific point in the conversation or after performing a specific action? If that's the case, what makes you think this has anything to do with the handover protocol? Try to reproduce the error while running the bot locally using a tunneling service like [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) so you can see what line is throwing the error. Also, why did you include `**` in your code? You can't bold a piece of code like that.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, as suggested, I have tried to reproduce the error using ngrok but no luck. I did not find any line which causing this error. Here It just displayed the same service error message(attached image in my question) as displayed in cloud. Please suggest your opinion.

Please never mind, I didnt know about bold formatting about code. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code? When you say you're using ngrok, are you just running the bot locally or actually debugging the bot? Have you set the debugger to break on all exceptions?

Comment: @KyleDelaney , Yes I am using Visual Studio code. I run the bot in debugging mode  with necessary break points. But no luck. :(

Comment: You're saying you've checked the "All Exceptions" check box like you can see in this tutorial? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hi Kyle, it has been resolved. Error due to duplicate event. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Go ahead and post that as an answer so you can accept it